# News scraping multiple url inside a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, scrapy, newspaper3k

So I am try using Newspaper3k for scraping content of a few website.In the library the function `Article()` only take a single url.Is this possible to iterate a dataframe a full of url to **scrape** it automated?My df is like this

```
df = ['https://www.liputan6.com/bisnis/read/4661489/erick-thohir-apresiasi-transformasi-digital-pos-indonesia','https://ekonomi.bisnis.com/read/20210918/98/1443952/pos-indonesia-gandeng-nujek-perluas-segmen-pengiriman','https://www.republika.co.id/berita/qzkxdm380/perkuat-layanan-pt-pos-indonesia-gandeng-kurir-wanita']
```

I try a few possible answer like this

```
for x in df.iterrows():
    print(x)
a = Article(x,language='id')
b = a.download()
c = a.parse()
```

But it get a error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I also try

```
a = Article(url=x in df.iterrows(),language='id')
b = a.download()
c = a.parse()
author = a.authors
date = a.publish_date
text = a.text

combine = {'author':author,'date':date,'text':text}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=combine)
```

but got an error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I try a few more codes I really appriciated if get a help.Thanks

Comment: If you have any issues using Newspaper3k please reference my [Overview Document](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview) for this Python Package.   It's worth noting that Newspaper3k is no longer supported thus a new news parser is in the works and will be released soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df` is not a dataframe, it's a list. Just iterate through the list.

```
from newspaper import Article
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://www.liputan6.com/bisnis/read/4661489/erick-thohir-apresiasi-transformasi-digital-pos-indonesia','https://ekonomi.bisnis.com/read/20210918/98/1443952/pos-indonesia-gandeng-nujek-perluas-segmen-pengiriman','https://www.republika.co.id/berita/qzkxdm380/perkuat-layanan-pt-pos-indonesia-gandeng-kurir-wanita']

rows = []
for url in urls:
    try:
        a = Article(url,language='id')
        a.download()
        a.parse()
         
        author = a.authors
        date = a.publish_date
        text = a.text
        
        print(author, date, text)
        row = {'url':url,
               'author':author,
               'data':date,
               'text':text}
        
        rows.append(row)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        row = {'url':url,
        'author':'N/A',
        'data':'N/A',
        'text':'N/A'}
        
        rows.append(row)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Comment: Its great thanks,but when I try to ```print``` it return 3 ```values``` but when I try to converted into dataframe using ```new_df = pd.DataFrame({'author':[author]})``` it only return the last value of the ```print``` . Any idea about this?

Comment: it prints 3 values, because thats what it says with `print(author, date, text)`. As far as only getting the last value when converting into a dataframe, I suspect you don't have the logic correct with the for loop. You are probably overwriting your list after each iteration. I adjusted the code so you can get the output into a dataframe